# Magento payment bridge "This payment method is currently unavailable"

Tags: magento

Recently I have upgrade enterprise magento to 1.13.0.2. Also set up payment gateway as it is mandatory.We are using cybersource payment gateway. On checkout page shows an error 'This payment method is currently unavailable'.
[image]

Comment: did you changed the database password ?

Comment: I am facing same problem to change db pass. Please have a look into it . magento.stackexchange.com/q/136433/28515

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This  might cause by following reasons;
1) Ips are not allowed
2) If its in stage/test server, this issue may come if the site is password protected
3) SSL is not properly installed or have error(If ssl is using)

Before checking above points make sure you have added correct merchant_id and transaction key;
php tools/merchant.php -i your_merchant

My issue was due to #2.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this means that the payment method is properly setup but is not enabled in the backend admin panel.

Navigate to...

> admin/system_config/edit/section/payment
>   Or if your payment method settings are in a custom route search your `core_config_data` table for it:

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE '%cybersource%';
```

OR similar...

Find the value that corresponds with 'enabled' and ensure it is set to 1 for default scope and all the store/website scopes you're testing.

If the value for enabled/active is not present in `core_config_data` you need to find your payment method route through admin and save it that way as the configuration entries are only populated after the initial save.

Ensure you flush cache and check if the issue persists.

If it does, search your repo for the error message text and var_dump/die above to understand what's missing.